# Adding a new object to a SQL Server database using LINQ C#/MVC does simply returns me to the same page without adding records to the database

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

My Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Customers Customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        _db.Customers.Add(Customer);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
return View(Customer);
}
```

My Model:

```
    public class Customers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set;}
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
   // public ICollection<CustomerData> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

From my View:

```
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

Create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add New Customer</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.State)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Zip)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Zip)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Zip)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

When I run this code, all of the fields end up getting rendered from the subsequent Create.cshtml.  Filling in all of the forms and clicking the submit button sends me back to "Index", but does not add any of my fields into the database.  It seems like the Create action is not being hit.  Anyone have any advice for a beginner?

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on your controller is it hit?  If it is,  is there anything in your customer object?

Comment: can you post your entire POST method?

Comment: @MattBodily I don't think it is hitting hitting the HTTPGET or HTTPPost actions.  I'm using VS2013 and have been experiencing issues with the debugger, so I'm not 100% sure it is working correctly.

Comment: @Jonesy Updated the post with the remainder of the POST method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, thanks for everyone responding so quickly.  Turns out, I had my db set to deploy on debug somehow.  When I unchecked deploy on my project debug properties, everything worked.